# Locking Website - Weird Behaviour

Tags: apache-httpd

While testing locking directories or locking the entire website in Centos7 (httpd 2.4) , i've noticed the following weird behaviour :

if i locked the entire website :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/vhost100
 ServerName vhost100.test.local
 ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/vhost100_error_log.log"
 CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/vhost100_access_log.log" combined
 <Directory "/www/vhost100">
 Options Indexes
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
    <Directory "/www/vhost100">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Protected Area"
        AuthUserfile /etc/httpd/authfile
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

and try :

```
 elinks http://vhost100.test.local
```

after submitting username/password based on the authfile ,login authentication fails and the following message rises :

```
 "This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the 
  document requested.Either you supplied the wrong credentials (eg bad 
  password) or your browser doesnt understand how to suppy the credentials 
  required"
```

Error logfile have recording nothing.

On the contrary, if i modified the vhost and adjust locking to subdirectory (restricted) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/vhost100
 ServerName vhost100.test.local
 ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/vhost100_error_log.log"
 CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/vhost100_access_log.log" combined
 <Directory "/www/vhost100">
 Options Indexes
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
 <Directory "/www/vhost100/restricted">
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Protected Area"
      AuthUserfile /etc/httpd/authfile
      Require valid-user
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

and try :

```
elinks http://vhost100.test.local/restricted
```

Authentication works and you can view the protected content!
Any idea or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you customized the error pages? This might be a variant on "additionally, an error occurred while trying to display the error page".

Answer (score 0):

Avoid two competing `<Directory "/www/vhost100">` declarations.

Comment: Hello ,i removed the one <Directory> section but nothing really changed

Comment: I setup a new VM (Centos 7) and faced once again the same behaviour.Frankly, i cant understand what is the problem...if i locked down a directory it works ,but if i locked the entire website not.

Comment: Does it need an `AuthBasicProvider file` setting?

Comment: Unfortunately not,still the same results

Answer (score -1):

The following section has been set twice in your original configuration: `<Directory "/www/vhost100">`